# Redirect Http URL to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.2

I am trying to redirect URL http://devabc.xyz.com/jsp/rq.jsp?action=switch&page=main to  https://devabc.xyz.com/jsp/rq.jsp?action=switch&page=main based on the query string parameter. I tried below in apache configuration. But its not working.

```
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^devabc\.xyz\.com$ [NC]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /jsp/        [NC]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /rq.jsp      [NC]
       RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=switch&page=main [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://devabc\.xyz\.com [R,L]
```

Let me know what I am missing.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I just figured. Adding below fixed the issue.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^devabc\.xyz\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /jsp/        [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /rq.jsp      [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=switch&page=main [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://devabc\.xyz\.com$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks